# Crop letters from a single image and create a dataset

Tags: dataset, image-generation

[image]

- Above image has handwritten hindi / deavanagari letters all on a single

  image.
- Task is to Prepare a dataset from the given assignment.jpg image using image

  processing tools
- Idon't have clarity whether i can use photoshop editing tools like adobe photoshop etc.
- If image processing tools mean opencv , is it really possible to create like a emnist like dataset from single image.
- I am not able to come up with any way to seperate the letters from eachother

Comment: You can try datascience.SE